# PHP curl post image from URL

Tags: php, curl

Currently, to POST image from local folder I use curl and PHP, here is my code:

```
$url = 'http://myprestashop.com/api/images/products/1';

$image_path = 'C:\\my_image.png';
$key = 'My web service key';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key.':');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => '@'.$image_path));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

How can I POST image from URL (http://imageserver.com/image.jpeg) instead of local folder (C:\my_image.png)? Is it possible?

Comment: I think you need like this. Get response from prestashop.com and when you display curl need to display your images from other server if i am right then its possible

Answer (score -1):

Just change your image path and try this code.

```
$url = 'http://myprestashop.com/api/images/products/1';

$data = array('key' => 'My web service key', 'image_path' => '@/home/user/test.png');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I need to get image from URL, not from directory as in your code

Comment: Then why don't you just post the url of image and store it in db.

Comment: That is not the case I need, I need to POST image to PrestaShop WebService what it requires, not the URL